# Read forward slash from JFileChooser file-name dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I need to read a file name from JFileChooser file-name input dialog which consist of forward slash '/'. But it's taking as a backslash '\' Path Separator in windows environment.

Comment: `/` will only be applicable under *nix based OS's.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I know that. If i give input file name as "questions/30228778/read-forward". The file name I get is only "read-forward", an not the whole. The rest is considered as path.

Comment: Actually JFileChooser will return the path suitable for the machine it is running on. In case of windows it is backward slash and for Mac it is forward slash.

Comment: @akhil_mittal What is the solution for it. I do not want the user to edit the file name and take out forward slashes. Is there any way that the application can read a forward slash from JFileChooser?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `JFileChooser` will return the path suitable for the machine it is running on. In case of windows it is backward slash and for Mac it is forward slash. The `JFileChooser` returns a File object and by calling `getCanonicalPath` you get the path which has a different format depending on the OS.

SO IMO **there seems to be no clean way** at least. One possibility is to read the file name and then replace backward slash with forward slash. But I doubt it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Will it make any difference if I use FileDialog instead of JFileChooser? or remembering last_used directory and UI will be the only changes I get switching to FileDialog